# What is better create new table or add columns in existing table

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my database, i have payment table
paymentid, amount, duedate, approvalcode, status, transactionid etc.

payment table has already 15 columns.

if i want to store tip, tax, disount against paymentid.

what is better

create new paymentdetails table with one to one relationship

or

add columns in same payment table?

pls help.

payment table has almost more than 50000 records. so what is really good for database.

Comment: Read E-R and normal forms to understand how to reach on a good decision.

Comment: 50.000 rows really isn't much.

Comment: if that column data would not be used in every query then i can create new table right?

Comment: if i add columns in same table
is there any performance issue? when i m using join.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With such small tables I don't see a reason for not putting the new columns in the existing table.

You would do that if

- you hit some kind of limits (number of columns, total size of table) of the RDBMS
- the data in the columns is huge and only used in few queries

Comment: if that column data would not be used in every query then i can create new table right?

Comment: that question is kind of backward. Normally you would prefer to have the columns in the same table. Only if something else forces you to do it you would create a new table. You CAN always create the columns in a new table, but you SHOULD almost never do it.

Comment: Only if something else forces you to do it you would create a new table. ??
didnt get u?? can u pls explain.

Comment: jens last question is if all new columns value is mostly null then ? what to do create new table or add in exisitng

Comment: I'd still put it in the same table.

Answer (score 3):

Generally, I work on the premise that attributes of something/entity/object should be stored against the something/entity/object.  Typically, I only split out into a new table when there is a one to many relationship - so an attribute that has multiple values (e.g. person and qualifications held)

I would add them to the payment table - although perhaps you have an order table they would more suitably relate to?

You will need to keep in mind whether you will need indexes over these columns though - if you add indexes, you could overburden your table and deteriorate performance but you would probably only add indexes in instances where you used the columns in joins and they don't sound like the sort of thing you would need to join on.

Comment: if i add columns in same table is there any performance issue? when i m using join.
bcz this new columns not useful in every query. it is just when i want to show in report

Comment: Usually, the addition of numeric/decimal columns won't have an effect on performance since these are very compact types of data. If you use decimal(10,2) you'll likely only be adding a byte for each column. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html

Comment: if my new columns is paymentreceipt datatype is text then? very big column

Comment: It might have some performance degredation if it was very big and used in  WHERE, JOIN, and GROUP BY clauses. Receipt data is probably something you would not use for reports, and only retain for audit purposes so it wouldn't need to be returned by queries requiring a rapid response. I'd test your key reports for potential impact by creating a temp table of the same structure plus the col in question (populated with some dummy data) and see how it performs.  At a later date you can always move the column off to a table to optimise it aggressively but for now stick to important stuff :-)